# cvs2svn or svn importer

Tags: cvs2svn, version-control-migration

I need to convert CVS to SVN, and I have found two tools, [CVS2SVN](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/) and [SVN importer](http://www.polarion.com/downloads/svn.php). Can someone suggest which tool is best . Its on a linux box, CVS and SVN resides on different linux boxes and migration has to be done with full history. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I chose cvs2svn  its a powerful tool and worked like a charm. Copied the cvs files from a machine and moved it to other machine then carried my migration.